# Changing protected mode settings for different zones in IE via C# code

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, registry

I have developed a automation tool using selenium but I get a exception stating " Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones" while initiating the IE driver.

I am looking for a way to programmatically to change the Protected Mode Settings at the start of program execution and revert it back at the end of execution.

Please share your suggestions and ideas for implementing this.